# End users getting "can't find project or library" error

Tags: vba

I'm trying to write a simple macro using a few user forms that will be used by many different users; is there a simple way to avoid end users having errors like "can't find project or library"?

That's already popped up, hoping to avoid any future issues.

Edit: the errors they're receiving right now have been on the following line of code - it's been 2 separate users:
invDate = Format(CDAte(invDateTextBox.Value), "mm/dd/yyyy")

Comment: Are you referencing any libraries in your VBE that your users won't already have enabled on their computers? It would help if you show us what portion of your code is causing errors on their machines.

Comment: Are your users all running the same version and bitness of the VBA host application (guessing Exce) and operating system? Does the form use non-standard controls?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out, used VBA.Format(.... 
at least worked on one users computer that was having trouble